# Python - Dynamically importing modules and assigning them local names

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, python-import, dynamically-generated

I'm fairly new to python, so I apologize for my lack of knowledge.

This is what I'm looking to do:

Say I currently have the following

```
import pandas as py
import numpy as np
...
import somePackage as someName
```

I want to be able to do this through having a dictionary of packages and names, to achieve something like this

```
imports = {'pandas' : 'py', 'numpy' : 'np' ... 'somePackage' : 'someName'}
for package in imports.keys():
    import package as imports[package]
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in function [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) will do dynamic imports where the module name is specified in a variable.  And you can make the assignment by updating [globals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) directly:

```
>>> imports = {'random':'r', 'statistics':'s'}
>>> for package, target in imports.items():
        globals()[target] = __import__(package)

>>> r.randrange(100)
16
>>> s.mean([10, 20, 61])
30.333333333333332
```

Comment: While this is how you would do this, you probably shouldn't ;)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not?

Comment: @AnthonySottile

Comment: It'll render any good linter useless (such as pyflakes / flake8 pylint).  And just in general, using "magical" things such as `locals()`, `globals()`, `__import__`, `import *`, `inspect`, `eval`, `exec`, etc. often hurt the readability and maintainability of your code.